# Calculate average packet loss over time

Tags: c++, math, average

So I would like to calculate the average packet loss (in no. of packets) over time in my application (over the last 5 seconds for example)

I have the code that detects the packet loss, and it executes the following line:

```
playerRef->AveragePacketLossOverFiveSeconds += packetDiff; // Adds the number of packets lost to the average (a double)
```

Here is how I currently decay it over time:

```
 double ratio = 0.0002f * m_totalTimeSpentLastTick; // because I want it to be an average over the last 5 seconds 
 playerToUpdate->AveragePacketLossOverFiveSeconds -= playerToUpdate->AveragePacketLossOverFiveSeconds * ratio;
```

I know the code isn't entirely correct. It gives relatively good values when tested, but higher than they should actually be (because it doesn't decay properly over time.)

My question is: is there a way to fix this code so that I don't need to make use of lists and other more complicated stuff? I know I could, for example, just make  packet loss objects, timestamp them, put them in a list, and then decay the list by removing those older than 5 sec and then averaging the remaining, but I think there has be a simpler way.

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Can't you keep in memory a fifo of all packet loss information + time? Then, when new information is known, you remove from the fifo any value oldest than 5sec. You can decrease your total as exactly know the values you want to ignore...

Comment: As you want to track only last 5 seconds, you have to remember which values to drop from average, so a sliding window needed if you want more accurate averages. Perhaps a high-pass filter filter might match your requirements (window size = 1).